# what does $1 means in yacc, and how can I get its value

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I want to complete a parsing about varlist declaration,
like varlist:id comma varlist|id.
At this time, I need to set up a list about `var`.
So I write this code:

```
varlist: id comma varlist{ createtnode($1.idcontext);}
        |id{createtnode($1.idcontext);};
```

But I find `$1.idcontext` is not that `idcontext` I want which should be this id token's idcontext.

Now, `$1.idcontext` is this sentence 'varlist'. Without the code action, this grammar works correctly.

```
typedef struct{
    int* TC;
    int* FC;
}boolcode;
typedef struct {
    char* idcontext;
    int constvalue;
    int chain;
    boolcode ftentry;
}includes;

/* Value type.  */
#if ! defined YYSTYPE && ! defined YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
typedef struct{
    int classify;
    includes unique;
} YYSTYPE;
# define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
# define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
#endif

VARList: IDENcode COMMA VARList{
    if(YYDEBUG) 
    {printf("6\n");
    printf("%s\n",$1.idcontext);
    }
    varlistnode* newvar=malloc(sizeof(varlistnode));
    newvar->varname=$1.idcontext;
    newvar->value=0;
    newvar->next=NULL;
    mynotes->next=newvar;
    mynotes=mynotes->next;
}|IDENcode{
    if(YYDEBUG) 
    {printf("7\n");printf("%s\n",$1.idcontext);}
    varlistnode* newvar=malloc(sizeof(varlistnode));
    newvar->varname=$1.idcontext;
    newvar->value=0;
    newvar->next=NULL;
    mynotes->next=newvar;
    mynotes=mynotes->next;
};
```

The words wait recognize:

```
a,b,c,d
```

The result of `printf()` function:

```
7
d:
6
c,d:
6
b,c,d:
6
a,b,c,d:enter code here
```

Comment: Please try to make your question readable. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Also, it's always good to [read the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Actions)

Comment: This is [tag:c], not [tag:pascal]. Don't tag indiscriminately. How did `yylval.idcontext` get set in the first place? And where did you assign it to `VARList`?

Comment: @melpomene 'I want to complete a parsing' isn't English either. If you're going to fix it, *fix* it.

Comment: @user207421 It's only "not English" because it doesn't mean anything. I don't know what it means either, so I can't rephrase it. I fixed the spelling (and some of the formatting), at least.

Comment: @melpomene I agree. It doesn't mean anything. Cosmetic edits are pointless. However it isn't hard to deduce that all that is really intended is 'I want to parse'.

Comment: @user207421 I disagree that grammar/spelling fixes are cosmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem in this program is not visible in this question because the bug is in your lexical scanner.

You haven't included the flex file in the question, but it's reasonable to guess that it contains something like this:

```
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*  { yylval.unique.idcontext = yytext;  /* INCORRECT */
                             return IDENcode;
                           }
```

It should read

```
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*  { yylval.unique.idcontext = strdup(yytext);
                             return IDENcode;
                           }
```

`yytext` points into the scanner's internal buffer, whose contents are modified every time the scanner is called. What you're seeing is a mild version of this problem, because your input is very short; if the input were long enough that `yylex` needed to refill the buffer from the input file, then you would see complete garbage in your `idcontext` fields. If you want to use the string later, you need to make a copy of it (and then you need to remember to `free()` the copy when you no longer need it, which can be a bit of a challenge.)

---

The other possible issue -- and honestly I don't know whether you consider it a problem or not, because you did not specify what output you *expect* from your debugging trace -- is that your right-recursive rule:

```
varlist: id comma varlist  { createtnode($1.idcontext); }
       | id                { createtnode($1.idcontext); }
```

ends up calling `createtnode` on the `id`s in reverse order, because a bison reduction action is executed *when the rule is matched*. Using right-recursion like that means that the first `varlist` action to execute is actually the one corresponding to the last `id`.

If you want the actions to execute left to right, you need to use left-recursion:

```
varlist: varlist comma id  { createtnode($3.idcontext); } /* See below */
       | id                { createtnode($1.idcontext); }
```

Left-recursion has other advantages. For example, it does not require all the `id`s (and `comma`s) to pile up on the parser's internal stack waiting for the final reduction action.

Again, you don't show enough of your code to see how you use the result of these actions. It looks to me like you're trying to create a global linked list of variables, whose header you store in a global variable. (`mynotes` evidently points to the tail of the list, so it can't be used to recover the head.) If that's the case, then the change above should work fine. But it would be more normal to make the semantic value of `varlist` a list header, avoiding the use of global variables. That would result in code which looked more like this:

```
varlist: id comma varlist  { $$ = append($1, createtnode($3.idcontext)); }
       | id                { $$ = append(newlist(), createtnode($1.idcontext); }
```

Comment: Thank you！ All problems are sloved！